# Default values not supported in SQL CE 4 and EF 6 code-first

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce

I have the following code-first model:

```
  public class TestContext : DbContext
  {
    public TestContext() : base("Data Source=Test.db") { }
    public DbSet<Item> Items { get { return this.Set<Item>(); } }
  }

  public class Item
  {
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<SubItem1> SubItems1 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<SubItem2> SubItems2 { get; set; }
  }
  public class SubItem1
  {
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public Int32 ItemId { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public String Test { get; set; }
  }
  public class SubItem2
  {
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public Int32 ItemId { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
    public Int32 TestCode { get; set; }
  }
```

When used like this:

```
  using (var context = new TestContext())
  {
    context.Items.Add(new Item());
    context.SaveChanges();
  }
```

I get an an exception which says "Default values not supported". This exception is thrown from `DmlSqlGenerator.GenerateInsertSql` and propagated up.

Originally I got the exception with much more complex schema, but I was able to boil it down to this. Is this a limitation of SQL CE? How can I get around it and have a principal item with two sets of dependent items each of which have scalar values?

Comment: this might be helpfull https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/583c7839-22a4-460e-8665-3e5e3998a0d5/default-values-not-supported-exception-thrown-when-inserting-into-ce-40-with-entity-framework?forum=adodotnetentityframework

Comment: Can you please turn your comment into an answer?

Comment: I have done that. Before accepting it you can update the answer what exactly you needed to solve the issue so instead of link the actual  answer might help in future.

Comment: Hope the edit is okay, I've expanded on what the solution is in the post itself. Thanks, your answer was an immense help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is known issue with CE and EF but [here is a link to the MSDN forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/583c7839-22a4-460e-8665-3e5e3998a0d5/default-values-not-supported-exception-thrown-when-inserting-into-ce-40-with-entity-framework?forum=adodotnetentityframework) that describes the issue and the solution.

The gist of it is not to have an entity with only keys, be it a sole primary key or primary key and foreign keys. Adding a scalar column gets rid of the exception.